# I can not set ADS_UF_PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE flag in VBScript

Tags: windows, vbscript, active-directory

I converted this example to VBScript: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/modifying-user-cannot-change-password-winnt-provider.

When I run this code:

```
Option Explicit

Const ADS_UF_PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE = &H40

Sub SetUserCannotChangePassword (strDomain, strUser)
    Dim lUserFlags, oUser, strPath
    
    strPath = "WinNT://" + strDomain + "/" + strUser
    
    ' Bind to the group with the current credentials.
    Set oUser = GetObject (strPath)
    
    lUserFlags = oUser.Get ("userFlags")
    WScript.Echo "Original value = " & lUserFlags
    
    lUserFlags = lUserFlags Or ADS_UF_PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE
    WScript.Echo "Changed value = " & lUserFlags
    
    ' Modify the userFlags property.
    oUser.Put "userFlags", lUserFlags
    
    ' Commit the changes to the server.
    oUser.SetInfo

    WScript.Echo "Readed value = " & oUser.Get ("userFlags")
End Sub

SetUserCannotChangePassword "MyDomain.local", "MyUser"

Dim oUser, strPath

strPath = "WinNT://MyDomain.local/MyUser"
Set oUser = GetObject (strPath)
WScript.Echo "Re-readed value = " & oUser.Get ("userFlags")
```

I got this result:

```
C:\Users\Sipedo>CScript.exe /NoLogo Test.vbs
Original value = 513
Changed value = 577
Readed value = 577
Re-readed value = 513
```

I used the GUI (Active Directory Users and Computers) and saw that **User cannot change password** is not set. I manually set it and run my test program again.

Then I got this result:

```
C:\Users\Sipedo>CScript.exe /NoLogo Test.vbs
Original value = 577
Changed value = 577
Readed value = 577
Re-readed value = 513
```

Now I saw that the setting **User cannot change password** were lost!

(513 = &H201 = ADS_UF_SCRIPT Or ADS_UF_NORMAL_ACCOUNT
577 = &H241 = ADS_UF_SCRIPT Or ADS_UF_NORMAL_ACCOUNT Or ADS_UF_PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE)

I tried google but didn't find anything.
Thank you in advance for any advice.

Comment: Eh, what the...? *Speechless*

Comment: Welcome to SO.  How many domain controllers are in your domain?  Have you tried waiting for AD replication before calling `GetObject` the second time?  Have you tried targeting a specific domain controller?  Is the account context running your script permitted to perform that operation in your AD environment?

Comment: @leeharvey1 - I have three domain controllers. Two Windows Server 2019 Datacenter and one Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter. My current domain functional level is Windows Server 2012 R2. During testing, I logged in directly (RDP) to one of the Windows 2019 Servers as a user who is a member of the Domain Admins group. I have the Command Prompt launched with Run as administrator.